# pronunciation of foreign cities

Tags: pronunciation

When I mentioned to friends I had recently been to Benalmadena in Spain, I was corrected on its pronunciation. I had chosen to pronounce it in an English way rather than in a Spanish pronunciation. After all, I wouldn't say Paris how a Frenchman would say it.

If I use the native pronunciation of a foreign city I might look pretentious. If on the other hand I use the English pronunciation, I might then get corrected with the alternative.

Which is the correct convention please?

Many thanks.

Comment: I hate having to deal with this issue. OK. I'm not too good at pronouncing other people's words the native way, but just leave me alone. Also, I don't care - I like pronouncing it Chip port'l. it sounds more pleasing to my ear. Just leave me alone. Should I teach them how to pronounce *Rosh HaShannah* "correctly"?

Comment: There is no ‘correct convention’. It depends on context. @BlessedGeek, are you talking about Chipotle, as in the food chain?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No. He's talking about the Jewish New Year. Everything at the restaurant is tref.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Rosh Hashana I know—I was talking about “Chip port’l”. Unless of course he likes to pronounce either Rosh Hashana or Benalmádena as “Chip port’l”, which I’d say is perhaps taking idiosyncratic pronunciation to a slightly exaggerated level.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ahh. I think he's referring to a dried (or smoked) jalapeño pepper.

Answer (score 1):

As with many things I believe the answer here is context.

With your "pretentious" friends use the native pronunciation "Paree" (and be prepared for a correction when you forget); with everyone else say "Paris", and in my city you'd have to add "France".